# Ubuntu upgrade left me with a blinking cursor after reboot

Tags: login, cursor

I had the blinking cursor and no login after an upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04.

My 18.04 was working fine and I had wifi connected and working and all drivers installed. I remembered my username and password as well.

After the upgrade, I rebooted to find a blinking cursor and nothing else...

Comment: I fixed it though.

First, I used the CTRL+ALT+F2 key combination (Press the 3 together at the same time) to enter tty2

I logged in by typing my username without the computer name (just your username, not 'username@computername') and then my password.

Next, I updated my computer with 'sudo apt update' then 'sudo apt dist-upgrade'.

Last I entered 'sudo startx' and I logged in fine. I restarted and it started fine.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Splendid! Please post that as an answer, and then click on the checkmark to show others it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it though. 
First, I used the CTRL+ALT+F2 key combination (Press the 3 together at the same time) to enter tty2 
I logged in by typing my username without the computer name (just your username, not 'username@computername') and then my password.
Next, I updated my computer with 'sudo apt update' then 'sudo apt dist-upgrade'. 
Last I entered 'sudo startx' and I logged in fine. I restarted and it started fine. I hope this helps!